# How do I connect OpenShift PHP to its MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

I'm still very new in uploading php and mysql online. Here is the link on where I uploaded my php files http://studcams-shadowj3yz.rhcloud.com/main.php

It contains a `config.php` and `connection.php` and here are the codes

For `config.php`

```
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));
```

For `connection.php`

```
$this->connect = mysqli_connect(constant("DB_HOST"), constant("DB_USER"), constant("DB_PASS"), constant("DB_NAME"), constant("DB_PORT"))
        or die("Could not connect to db");
```

This is how I connnect to openshift right? It displays `Could not connect to db`. How do I fix the this? Thanks!

Edited:

Ok now I've changed my code into this

```
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
        define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
        define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
        define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
        define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

        $dbhost = constant("DB_HOST");
        $dbport = constant("DB_PORT");
        $dbusername = constant("DB_USER");
        $dbpassword = constant("DB_PASS");
        $db_name = constant("DB_NAME");

        $this->connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword, "", $dbport) or die ("Connect Error: ".mysqli_error($this->connect));
        mysqli_select_db($this->connect, $db_name) or die("DB Error: ".mysqli_error($this->connect));
```

Now it displays `Connect Error:` but no other information.

Comment: Try using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to view the actual error that is returned, instead of just your "Could not connect to db" string.

Comment: updated my question. It doesn't display the `mysqli_error`

Comment: Could there be an object context problem (`$this->connect`)?

Comment: Have you tried stopping & starting your application? (not a restart)